# Warning: nonnull argument 'this' compared to NULL

Tags: c++, compiler-warnings

I know this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46895373/nonnull-argument-compared-to-null-in-c).

However I have a compiler warning which mentions `this` which makes a bit different from the question above.

As the above question's answer clearly states that the attribute in the warning is defined with

> **attribute**((nonnull));

Consider this class:

```
class ReferenceCounter {
    public:
        ReferenceCounter(void) : count_(0) {
        }

        ReferenceCounter& operator=(const ReferenceCounter& other_) {
            if (this != &other_) {
                count_ = other_.count_;
            }
            return *this;
        }

        void increment(void) {
            ++count_;
        }

        int decrement(void) {
            return this == NULL ? 0 : --count_;
        }

    private:
        int count_;
    };
```

Compiler warns for the `return this == NULL ? 0 : --count_;` line with

> warning: nonnull argument ‘this’ compared to NULL

Where is "this" decided to be *nonnull* here?

Note: *ReferenceCounter* is used only in one place as a pointer:

```
ReferenceCounter* r;
```

Which makes possible to be *NULL* so I don't understand why the compiler *complains* about this particular check and want to

1. understand
2. correct

Please don't shoot me about this code, it's not mine, just I'm forced to use it.

Comment: If `this` is `NULL`, your program has big, big problems.

Comment: if `this` is `NULL` how would be possible to call `decrement`? As I stated in the question I would like to **understand**.

Comment: `ReferenceCounter* r = NULL; r->decrement();` is undefined behavior, but usually crashs on the first member variable access. Probably the writer thought he could outsmart the compiler or so.

Comment: If `r` is `nullptr` (C++'s version of `NULL`) then `r->decrement();` is already Undefined Behavior and can crash, unpredictably corrupt your program or silently ignore the error. Once execution might reach the function's body it is already too late.

Comment: It's possible, unfortunately, but the program is broken. The compiler cannot pick off the more complicated versions of `ReferenceCounter* r = NULL; r->decrement();`, so a flawed program can be produced. As François points out, the test inside the function is too late, the program is already broken. The correction is to remove the test as it is meaningless.

Comment: It is interesting that the test occurs in `decrement` and not in `increment`, so this was likely some hack to "fix" a bug elsewhere that never was tripped over when calling `increment`. The program has a lurking bug that may be causing other problems that no one has noticed yet. Valgrind or Address Sanitizer may be able to help you track it down and kill it.

Comment: GCC and Clang have the flag `-fno-delete-null-pointer-checks` that enables this type of code to work. Yes, I know, it remains a bad thing to do.

Answer (score 3):

> Compiler warns for the return this == NULL ? 0 : --count_; line with
>
> warning: nonnull argument ‘this’ compared to NULL
>
> Where is "this" decided to be nonnull here?

The compiler will assume that `this` is always non-null, because it is undefined behavior when a member function is invoked on the null pointer value, i.e. when `ptr` in `ptr->decrement()` is a null pointer.

Comment: So it's "safe" to change `return this == NULL ? 0 : --count_;` to `return --count_;`?

Comment: @Daniel The two are functionally identical. `this == NULL` can reliably be assumed to be `false`, which mean the code is equivalent to `false ? 0 : --count_;` which is equivalent to `--count_;`. The difference is the latter is clearer in intent.

Comment: Well, yes. If you don't write the code in this "safe" way, the compiler will pretend you have written it this way ;)